# Add images and other text in QGIS 3.0.2 (Windows)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Today is my second day of using a GIS software. I have imported latitude, longitudes from csv into QGIS. I want that whenever users click on any location, they can see a pop with info: Country and State only, not all the fields that I see now.

[image]

Also, I want to add a field that will contain a hyperlink. In addition, I want to that users see the locations' image post clicking (or hover over). For this I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hcZPNL9yb8), but not helpful. Working file is [here](https://we.tl/hU3pSZsal5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Field Widgets to control what the user sees in the Attributes Form

Right click on layer name in Layer Panel > Properties > Attributes Form

#### For any fields you want to hide from the user, change the Widget Type to Hidden.

[image]

[image]

#### For a hyperlink, just add a text field and type the link into it.

#### For an image, use an Attachment Field Widget

Type the file path where it says Default Path, or put a unique file path in the field for each feature, and choose that field under data-defined settings.

[image]

Comment: I used a combination of Action and Toggle Editing mode to achieve the same. your method seems to be easier. Two questions: (1) How to put a unique file path in the field for each location ? The I am doing it is I right-click on the shape-file, and then Properties, then your view appears. But it seems like this path would be default for my every location. (2) If i share my project with another friend, will the image open if i send the images too ? I think it won't.

Comment: Put the file path in the field in the attribute table. You may need to add an additional field rather than using the same field that's setup with the "attachment" widget.

Comment: Put all the images in the same file as the project, and use relative file paths. Then share the whole file, and your friend should be able to see the images.

Comment: I have created a new field 'image path', and put 2 different images corresponding to 2 locations in the project folder.The screenshot is here https://bit.ly/2jWtlfh . Then I went to widgets > attachments > and entered paths , and selected relative paths, and then Document viewer as Image. See here please : https://bit.ly/2ICGwzN  and https://bit.ly/2rJjI7V  .. How do I see the image now ?

Comment: Also, is it possible to create a new column that contains hyperlink, and when viewers click on the location , they will get a pop-up with location details ( which we currently see) alongwith the new column with the "Clickable Hyperlink". Adding a text column is not useful when i have hundreds of locations and their corresponding hyperlinks

Comment: Put the hyperlink in a text column. It will display in the Identify Results window as a hyperlink.

Comment: all things done. The image problem persists. I added a new column to my dataset and put the location of the image corresponding to every location. Then I went to Attributes Form > New Field > Widget Type > Attachment > Relative Paths (Relative to Project Path) > Integrated Document View - Image. And I Shared the entire project folder including images to my friend, but the New Image Field  he sees is Blank, but I see the images correctly.

Comment: You should post that as a new question, with screenshots of your attribute table and of the field widget settings.